# I now have 10 Atlas stones but no way to locate another atlas station

Tags: no-mans-sky

I went to my 10th Atlas station expecting to get given my 10th Atlas Stone. However the only option was a greyed-out one to hand my 10 stones over. As I only had 9 stones (I guess I must have missed one / lost one along the way or something) the only option was to explore the galaxy again.

So I left the station and went hunting for another Atlas stone. I found one from a trader at a space station and then went hunting for an anomaly so I could re-trigger the atlas path.

I found an anomaly but didn't get given the expected 'resume your Atlas hunt' option (or whatever it's called). Just the options for exploration resources or universe shortcut. So I'm a bit stumped on what to do now.

**Now that I have 10 atlas stones, how can I get to an Atlas station to complete this path?**

Comment: You are looking for Atlas Interface, not Atlas Station.
Atlas Interface is part of the Atlas Quest (bugged so far).
Atlas Station is a red dot in your map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands you are no longer able to do the Atlas quest as leaving the final station makes it stop existing, meaning that you cannot complete it.

This has been an issue since launch and it appear that it has not been addressed in any of the [patch notes](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/news/) on the official website for the game.

The issue was documented by a few different people such as Escapist writer [Shamus Young](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=33790) and Forbes writer [Paul Tassi](http://www.forbes.com/sites/insertcoin/2016/08/22/no-mans-skys-futile-atlas-ending-embodies-everything-wrong-with-the-game/#143cf80c4742). The articles are pretty negative but talk about having the same problem that you are having under the same circumstances.

Comment: Aw man, that Shamus Young article covers off *exactly* my experience of the game. :( I guess there is no solution to my issue then. I'll just read patch notes when the next release comes out and see if they've patched it.